# how can I create an ssh tunnel with autossh in mac

Tags: macos, autossh

I have the following ssh tunnel and want to restore on connection broken. In order to achieve it, I was thinking of using autossh but not sure how to do it on mac os.
Here is my ssh connection string:

```
ssh -4 -C -i /Users/paolo/id_ed25519_mykey -D *:8888 -p 321 root@testxyz.hopto.org
```

anyone can help me with it?